# i have error see vue.js code when reload vue.js single application

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

[this image of web page when reload page i see vue js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXEwg.jpg)i need to sort array of objects in **Vue** with to attributes of the object but Vue go in infinite loop to sorting

Comment: Is there any error or warning on console?

Comment: this is only warning  [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640621/im-tsm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498962/how-to-hide-vue-js-code-when-reload-page/53499519#53499519

Comment: solve this question see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498962/how-to-hide-vue-js-code-when-reload-page/53499519#53499519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this `v-cloak` to your html it didn't load html until load its css