# How to hide vue js code when reload page?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, cdn, singlepage

I have a webpage application coded with Vue when reload page the code of Vue in the HTML load with code view and hide.

I need to hide this code when reload page

```
<script src="cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> <script src="cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> <script src="./js/vue.js"></script>
```

[image: image of what happen when reload page]

Comment: How you load Vue?

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
              <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
              <script src="./js/vue.js"></script>

Comment: i used each one but have the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak), it is a directive to prevent this behavior.

In your css file you add this:

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

And for the text you add the `v-cloak` attribute

```
<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```